# What is the idiomatic way to iterate over a binary file?

Tags: python, file, iterator

With a text file, I can write this:

```py
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # handle the line
```

This is equivalent to this:

```py
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
        # handle the line
```

This idiom is documented in [PEP 234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) but I have failed to locate a similar idiom for binary files.

With a binary file, I can write this:

```py
with open(path, 'rb') as file:
    while True:
        chunk = file.read(1024 * 64)
        if not chunk:
            break
        # handle the chunk
```

I have tried the same idiom that with a text file:

```py
def make_read(file, size):
    def read():
        return file.read(size)
    return read

with open(path, 'rb') as file:
    for chunk in iter(make_read(file, 1024 * 64), b''):
        # handle the chunk
```

Is it the idiomatic way to iterate over a binary file in Python?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in way to do this, but a wrapper function is easy enough to write:

```
def read_in_chunks(infile, chunk_size=1024*64):
    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        else:
            # The chunk was empty, which means we're at the end
            # of the file
            return
```

Then at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> from chunks import read_in_chunks
>>> infile = open('quicklisp.lisp')
>>> for chunk in read_in_chunks(infile):
...     print chunk
... 
<contents of quicklisp.lisp in chunks>
```

Of course, you can easily adapt this to use a with block:

```
with open('quicklisp.lisp') as infile:
    for chunk in read_in_chunks(infile):
        print chunk
```

And you can eliminate the if statement like this.

```
def read_in_chunks(infile, chunk_size=1024*64):
    chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)
    while chunk:
        yield chunk
        chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)
```

Comment: I had assumed there was some built-in way that I was just overlooking. Since there seems to not be a built-in way, this is is easy to read and straight forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

Try:

```
chunk_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024  # MB

with open('large_file.dat','rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(chunk_size), b''):
        handle(chunk)
```

[`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) needs a function with zero arguments.

- a plain [`f.read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) would read the whole file, since the `size` parameter is missing;
- `f.read(1024)` means call a function and pass its return value (data loaded from file) to `iter`, so `iter` does not get a function at all;
- `(lambda:f.read(1234))` is a function that takes zero arguments (nothing between `lambda` and `:`) and calls `f.read(1234)`.

Comment: Yeah, the sentinel trick with iter() is really neat! (Although I don't like lambdas, so I would have made a function).

Comment: That works! Thanks. It is hard loosing old idioms (Perl) and learn new ones while still being reasonably productive.

Comment: This works... but it's a bit difficult to read in my opinion.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro, @Jason Baker: I assumed OP wants to learn why his `iter` call didn't work. Writing an iterator is what I probably also would do in this case, unless working in an interactive prompt.

Comment: @liori - Good point.  I missed the fact that the OP was iterating over `f.read`.

Comment: `functools.partial(f.read, numBytes)` should work too in place of the `lambda`

Comment: The sentinel should be an empty bytestring, `b''`. String literals are Unicode objects in Python 3 or with `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in Python 2.

Answer (score 13):

The Pythonic way to read a binary file iteratively is using the built-in function `iter` *with two arguments* and the standard function `functools.partial`, as described in the [Python library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

> **`iter`**(*object*[, *sentinel*])
>
> Return an iterator object. The first argument is interpreted very differently depending on the presence of the second argument. Without a second argument, *object* must be a collection object which supports the iteration protocol (the `__iter__()` method), or it must support the sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments starting at `0`). If it does not support either of those protocols, `TypeError` is raised. If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then *object* must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call *object* with no arguments for each call to its `__next__()` method; if the value returned is equal to *sentinel*, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.
>
> See also Iterator Types.
>
> One useful application of the second form of `iter()` is to build a block-reader. For example, reading fixed-width blocks from a binary database file until the end of file is reached:
>
> ```py
> from functools import partial
>
> with open('mydata.db', 'rb') as f:
>     for block in iter(partial(f.read, 64), b''):
>         process_block(block)
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Nearly 10 years after this question and now Python 3.8 has the `:=` *Walrus Operator* described in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

To read a file in chunks idiomatically and expressively (with Python 3.8 or later) you can do:

```py
while chunk := file.read(1024 * 64):
    process(chunk)
```

Comment: i got   while chunk := input_file.read(1024 * 64):
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using Python 3.8+?

Comment: Why can't that loop be trivially rewritten with 2-art iter? Other answers seem to do exactly that

Comment: I would agree with @Osman-pasha that it's untrue, or at least a stretch, that this can't be trivially rewritten with 2-arg `iter()`. Depends what you mean by trivially I suppose. But I certainly agree this is a lot simpler to read - rather than composing a new function (with lambda or partial) then passing that to another function to call as a callback - this simply just calls the function!

Comment: I agree with you and I removed the comment. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

In Python 3.8+, there is a [new assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) `:=` - known as the "walrus operator" - that assigns values to variables. See [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) for more details. Thus, to read a file in chunks, you could do:

```
def read_in_chunks(file_path, chunk_size=1024):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        while chunk := f.read(chunk_size):
            yield chunk  # or process the chunk as desired
```

Comment: I don't think this adds any information that is missing in previous answers.

Comment: Almost 2 years earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218911/480982