# Mining massive data sets in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataset of over 5GBs. Is there a way I can train my model with this data chunk by chunk in a Stochastic Gradient Descent kind of way? In other words, break the set in 5 chunks of 1 GB each, and then train parameters.

I want to do this in a Python environment.

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710748/process-large-data-in-python

Comment: The link above has very little to do the question. This is a machine-learning problem, not a data processing problem.

Comment: The Question is not too board. Machine Learning algo's have an underlying process that does or does not lend itself to chunking the data. Some Scikit Learn algo's have "recently" been implemented to work with partial data sets, others have not. Some of the same type of  algo implementation in other languages or packages can or can not take partials.  So, which python package accepts partials is key to determine if you can use chunking to run code in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. SGD in scikit learn has `partial fit` ; use it with your chunks

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

```
partial_fit(X, y[, classes, sample_weight]) Fit linear model with Stochastic Gradient Descent.
```